# Problem when using JQuery Autocomplete as a Google Maps Api v3 map contro

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm building a map control for Google Maps API v3. The map control contains the JQuery UI Autocomplete widget.

The map control is coded as a JQuery UI widget.The code works fine when used standalone and has a glitch when used as a Map Control via:

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(document.getElementById('myControl'));

The glitch is that when autocomplete retrieves the data and shows the dropdown list with available options, the list seems to be perfectly built except for the values not being showed. If I click on an item the textbox of the autocomplete widget perfectly show the value selected.

So, wrapping up, the autocomplete widget seems to fail to SHOW the values of the dropdown list when used with google maps api v3 as a map control.

Any clue what's happening? work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer to the question:

My widget uses another some custom widgets (all under the same .js file) whose only responsibility is styling some elements of the control with JQuery UI CSS classes.

If I perform this styling on my map control widget AND remove the reference to the other .js file in the html.... everything works fine. In fact, if I do not use the styling widgets from my map control widget WHEREAS maintaining the reference to the .js file, the problem persists.

So it seems it must be something about how the styling widgets library file is formatted.

If anyone has still something to point out about the issue, help is welcome!